# SQL Query for Getting a Duplicate Record and Show it in One Row in Gridview

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

So I need to show a data with duplicate record into one row only.

Please see the image [Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fDzK.png)

The Employee has more than one job but I only need to see the amployees empno, firstname, last name, enity and location so I only need one row of a record.

I tried using the `SELECT DISTINCT` but it's not working.

Here's my codes

```
Protected Sub BindUsersGrid()

    Dim Con As New SqlConnection
    Con = getConn()

    Dim ds As DataSet = GetRecord("SELECT DISTINCT MASTERID, USERID, EMPNO, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ENTITY, LOCATION, EMAIL, BDATE, SEX, CONTACT_NO, IS_RESIGNED, LOCALNAME, " & _
                                    "REGION, COUNTRY " & _
                                    "FROM EMP_MASTERTBL " & _
                                    "ORDER BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MASTERID")

    Me.myDataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Me.gvUsers.DataSource = Me.myDataTable
    Me.gvUsers.DataBind()
    Session("gvData") = myDataTable

End Sub
```

What could be the problem to my codes? Can you give me another ideas or sample or another code to use for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.  What is the output from this actual query and why is it wrong?

Comment: The actual output of this query is the image that I posted. It shows two record or two rows of the same employee. I only need one row of the same employee details that I get.

Comment: Which _columns_ do you actually want in the result set.  Your `DISTINCT` should mention _only_ these columns.  My guess is that the two records you showed us are _not_ distinct, and differ in one or more columns (thought not in those which are being shown).

Comment: the columns that I actually want in the result set are Empno, firstname, lastname, entity and location. Yes the two records differ in one column which is the jobtitle.

Comment: Remove the distinct keyword and post the actual result of your query so that you'll see which columns are not similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `SELECT DISTINCT`, the database will return records which are distinct with regard to *all* the columns.  This means that if you want records which are distinct with regard to 4 columns, but you select 5, then you could get what appears to be duplicates in your result set.  From what you told us, the following query might be along the lines of what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPNO, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ENTITY, LOCATION
FROM EMP_MASTERTBL
ORDER BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
```